# Capture groups in 1 line with fixed delimiters

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm a beginner at regex and still don't understand a lot. I apologize in advance from any wrong notations or missing information :(

I need to extract groups from an e-mail subject where I have to use each value further on in a process to use as a folder or document name.

Example: `123456/TEXT/567890/01Moretext`

I need to get the following pieces of text:

```
123456
TEXT
567890
01Moretext
```

in **seperate regex commands**.

So far I have:

1. `^\d{6}`, which gives me `123456`
2. `(?<=/)[^/]*`, which gives me `TEXT`
3. **I can't figure out how to extract the third group**, `567890`
4. `[^/]*$`, which gives me `01Moretext`

Would appreciate any help that can prevent my head from exploding!

Comment: Why not split on `/`?

Comment: I thought I was doing that? I'm not even sure how to do this now and how to capture it in  a regex...Like how to capture the first group and how then the second group....

Comment: The problem description sounds like you are using a language or tool which returns the whole match as "group 0" and the first parenthesized expression as group 1. Without seeing your code, we can only speculate. Please review the [tag:regex] tag description, which explains what you need to include in your question.

Comment: I'm using the regex in a OCR scanning tool "Umango" where the regexes all start with REGEX(...) I don't know what to add otherwise....

Comment: Try writing the pattern as `/(?<=\/)[^\/]+|[^\/]+(?=\/)/gm` See https://regex101.com/r/oym1v0/1

Comment: I got 3 groups working:

for group 1:

    ^\d{6}

for group 2:

    (?<=/)[^/]*

for group 4:

    [^/]*$

but i can't get the third group working.

Comment: See `^\d{6}/[^/]*/\K[^/]+` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oym1v0/2). If that does not work, try `[^/]+(?=/[^/]*$)` - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/oym1v0/3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
[^/]+(?=/[^/]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oym1v0/3). *Details*:

- `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `(?=/[^/]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `/` and then one or more chars other than `/` till the end of string.